# C# system command, communicating with GIT (automatically remember password)

Tags: c#

I want to make an updating exe that when i click on it either it will download or uploads data. The problem is that whenever i execute `git pull origin master` i have to enter the password.

This is what i tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GitUpdate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GIT updating");


            Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "git";
            cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "git pull origin master";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.Start();

            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("MY_PASSWORD_HERE");
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());


            Console.WriteLine("GIT updated ...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Also i know that there are git libraries for C# and options to remember the password, but i want to make it exe style, really need this.

Comment: So why going the unconventional way if there are indeed libraries for that?

Comment: If you want "exe style", why not use one of the libraries, and wrap it in your own exe?

Comment: Does your git repository support direct authentication?
For example, here in the company when configuring the remote URL, just add the password in it. http://user:password@6.2.5.92/repo/proj.git

Comment: i will use this type of program in other projects, i need something like `expect` from linux if you heared about it

Comment: You could store the credentials the first time your pushing (would require you to push manually, not sure if that is acceptable in your case). `git config credential.helper store`. Also: why not make a bat script, saves you the overhead a .net vm